# How to suggest tags to be merged?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

On Stack Overflow the tags [quartz](/questions/tagged/quartz) and [quartz-scheduler](/questions/tagged/quartz-scheduler) are referring to the [same thing](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). Should I just retag all [quartz](/questions/tagged/quartz) questions to [quartz-scheduler](/questions/tagged/quartz-scheduler) or is there a way that these two  merged automatically? Also can [quartz](/questions/tagged/quartz) be removed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have essentially two options here:

1. If you have [at least 2500 reputation and a score of 5 in those tags](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) (earned from upvotes to questions and answers you've posted carrying that tag), you can [propose a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/quartz/synonyms) yourself.

   Just type in `quartz-scheduler` and click the "Suggest" button. Your suggestion will be placed into the [Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) queue, where other users can vote on it. If enough users agree with your suggestion, the proposed tag will become a synonym of the original tag, causing all questions originally tagged with one to point to the other.
2. Alternatively, you can simply post a question here tagged with [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) and/or [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request), and a moderator will merge the tags for you.  For example, as was done [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89448/merge-web-scraping-and-webscraping-tags) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79039/2147483647-retag-to-integer-overflow), both of which have now been completed.

   In addition to being the only option for users with insufficient rep, this is particularly handy if you aren't *sure* about the retag or synonym suggestion. Tagging such a question with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) gives the community a chance to voice their opinions about the change before it gets implemented. This is a courtesy you should extend for any *major* tag changes.

The one option you generally *shouldn't* follow is retagging all of the existing questions yourself. There are a couple of reasons for this:

1. It doesn't prevent anyone from coming along later and using the tag you attempted to abolish. Essentially, you've only provided a temporary fix. And if the tag was created once and applied to multiple questions, chances are it'll get created by someone again.
2. Retagging a question "bumps" it back up to the top of the list. If it's an old question that's already been answered, it might be annoying to some. And if you retag a *bunch* of questions, this becomes *extremely* annoying for other users.

Answer (score 3):

If you have [2500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) you can suggest a [tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms). Once a synonym exists, any future posts using the tag [quartz](/questions/tagged/quartz) will automatically switch to using [quartz-scheduler](/questions/tagged/quartz-scheduler) instead, and it's very easy for a moderator to merge the tags so [quartz](/questions/tagged/quartz) won't exist at all.

If you don't have enough rep or score in that tag to suggest a synonym, you can post the request here and tag it [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request)

Comment: Don't you also need a tag-specific score?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I mentioned it later ("If you don't have enough rep or score in that tag"). I think it's 5

Comment: Whoops, didn't read that bit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have the reputation to suggest that they're synonyms.

What I usually do in those situations is write a tag wiki for the "wrong" tag, noting that it's redundant to another tag.