# Merge "ggplot2" and "qplot" tags

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Per the instructions in [How to suggest tags to be merged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92043/161858) can someone please merge  [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) and [qplot](/questions/tagged/qplot) as well as [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot)?

In R ([r](/questions/tagged/r)) the [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) package (library) contains the functions `ggplot` and `qplot`, where `qplot` is a wrapper around `ggplot`.  Thus, all questions relating to `qplot` and `ggplot` are really questions about [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2).

Since Stack Exchange views [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) as a versioned tag, I cannot do this merge myself, despite having sufficient rep and answer scores.

Comment: +1 Where's the mod that helps us?

Comment: +1 Good suggestion - no need to have superfluous tags lying around.

Comment: Many apologies to @baptiste. The question was flagged as a duplicate so I refunded the bounty in order to close it as such. But it was only when I double checked that I realised that the other question was much newer. I've added the bounty back from my rep.

Comment: @ChrisF And my apologies for not checking for dupes before asking my newer one. Feel free to close mine as a dupe if you feel its appropriate.

Comment: @joran - don't worry about posting duplicates. It happens to everyone at some point.

Comment: I would do the merge myself, but I'd rather defer to those more expert in the tags.

Comment: I don't know how many mods have much experience with R. FWIW Andrie and I are the two top SO users in [tag:ggplot2] (and baptiste is up there too, as well has being a significant contributor to the package's dev over the years) but for the definitive reference we could always ping @hadley (the package author) for his approval.

Comment: @ChrisF thanks, let's hope this gets some attention after 2 years

Comment: As another active member of the R tag I agree that these tags should be merged.

Comment: @ChrisF Would you be able to assist us in getting a concrete response from "the mods" as a group on this issue? I'd love to get some feedback about how we could more effectively lobby for this change.

Comment: @joran - it really needs someone with domain knowledge to give a definitive answer on this. Once that's done a mod can do the necessary. Get someone to post an answer with what needs merging.

Comment: @ChrisF Thank you for the pointer. I've answered my own question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the domain knowledge requested:

Merge:

- [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot)
- [qplot](/questions/tagged/qplot)
- [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2)  ( This should be the master )

(Circumstantial) evidence of domain knowledge:

- I have nearly 50K rep in the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag, with nearly 8K rep in the [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2), the proposed master tag.
- I co-authored *R for Dummies*
- I wrote the package *ggdendro* that extends `ggplot2` by adding support for dendrograms, published on CRAN.

Comment: Which one needs to be the master

Comment: @ChrisF ggplot2 should be the master

Comment: Though with 50K rep in the tag you should be able to suggest the synonyms yourself.

Comment: @ChrisF Nope, as per my question, SO considers `ggplot2` as a version specific tag, so I couldn't do it.

Comment: Ah - of course.

Comment: @ChrisF One of the ironies here is that the (superfluous) appendage of "2" on the package name is one of the longest running jokes in the R chat room (along with the package author's propensity for using underscores in function names). Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: @ChrisF is a StackOverflow rockstar!

Comment: Should the tags be merged (i.e `qplot` and `ggplot` actually replaced by `ggplot2`?

Comment: @ChrisF I propose that these should be synonyms, not replaced, to prevent the re-creation of new duplicate tags in future.  Good catch, thank you.